# react and socket.io infinite loop when clicking on a button to update game data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

I'm trying out socket.io and I have an issue with state updates when trying to make my tic-tac-toe game multiplayer.

On the `handleBoxClick` event, I want to to emit the data to the server (then player 2 will will send their turn and both tic-tac-toe grids will update).

However, in emitting the data to socket.io, I get an infinite loop if I use a useEffect (although the grids visually update). If I put the emit inside `handleBoxClick` (at the end of the function, after the state has updated), nothing happens (the emitting to the server seems to be the issue.

so, how am I supposed to effectively send the updated game data back and forth to the server layer without causing an infinite loop? the basic message examples show sending the emit in the `handleClick` (as the data is updating on the fly with the onChange as the message it typed). This doesn't work in the `handleBoxClick` function as the state isn't updated yet?

Here's the edited app code, can anyone please explain (with a code example) the proper flow here to avoid an infinite loop:

I have put a comment where the problem seems to be occurring.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Board } from './components/Board';
import { Scoreboard } from './components/Scoreboard';
import { ResetButton } from './components/ResetButton';

import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');

function App() {
  const winConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageReceived, setMessageReceived] = useState('');

  const [board, setBoard] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [xPlaying, setXPlaying] = useState(true);
  const [scores, setScores] = useState({ xScore: 0, oScore: 0 });
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);

  console.log('board', board);

  // ======================================================
  // ====================== For Socket.io ==================

  const joinRoom = () => {
    if (room !== '') {
      socket.emit('join_room', room);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('update_board_received', (data) => {
      setBoard(data.board);
      setXPlaying(data.xPlaying);
    });
  }, [socket]);

  // ======================================================
  // ====================== For Socket.io ==================

  // SENDING THE DATA HERE RESULTS IN AN INFINITE LOOP
  // IF I PUT 'board', 'room', and 'xPlaying' IN THE DEPENDANCY ARRAY
  // IF I DON'T PUT THEM IN THE DEPENDANCY ARRAY NOTHING HAPPENS!

  useEffect(() => {
   socket.emit('update_board_sent', {
    board: board,
    room: room,
    xPlaying: xPlaying,
  });

}, [board, room, xPlaying]);

  const handleBoxClick = (boxIdx) => {
    const updatedBoard = board.map((value, idx) => {
      // if the current index is equal to
      // the index that has been clicked
      // then return either "x" or "o"
      // (whoever is currently playing)
      // otherwise, return the value that was already present
      if (idx === boxIdx) {
        return xPlaying === true ? 'X' : 'O';
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    });

    const winner = checkWinner(updatedBoard);

    if (winner) {
      if (winner === 'O') {
        let { oScore } = scores;
        oScore += 1;
        setScores({ ...scores, oScore });
      } else {
        let { xScore } = scores;
        xScore += 1;
        setScores({ ...scores, xScore });
      }
    }


    setBoard(updatedBoard);

    // whenever handleclick is called
    // know that the current player has had their turn
    // so can change it to the next player ("X" or "O")

    // the value of xPlaying is the opposite of the current value of xPlaying
    setXPlaying(!xPlaying);

     // PUTTING THE EMIT HERE (after the states have updated) doesn't do anything
    // socket.emit('update_board_sent', {
    //   board: board,
    //   room: room,
    //   xPlaying: xPlaying,
    // });
  };

  const checkWinner = (board) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = winConditions[i];

      if (board[a] && board[a] === board[b] && board[b] === board[c]) {
        setGameOver(true);
        return board[a];
      }
    }
  };

  const resetBoard = () => {
    setGameOver(false);
    setBoard(Array(9).fill(null));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Scoreboard scores={scores} xPlaying={xPlaying} />
      <Board board={board} onClick={gameOver ? resetBoard : handleBoxClick} />
      <ResetButton resetBoard={resetBoard} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For completeness, here's the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
});

// listen to events
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`user Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  // specify an event called 'join room'
  // specify id of room you're joining (sent from frontend)
  // listening to it on the back end
  socket.on('join_room', (data) => {
    socket.join(data);
  });

  socket.on('update_board_sent', (data) => {
    socket.to(data.room).emit('update_board_received', data);
  });
});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('SERVER IS RUNNING');
});
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me with this please

Comment: `update_board_sent` triggers `update_board_received` which changes `board` that triggers `update_board_sent`

Comment: *after the states have updated* state doesn't update immediately

Comment: Oh, ok, I wasn't aware of that, thanks, I'll remove one of them and see if that works

Comment: So, I understand what you're saying but how do I structure the send and receive in the proper way then as both the server and the frontend have to send and receive requests? (I need to sent and received in there somewhere)

Without having a socket.emit and a socket.on the grids won't update